# Download iphone web pages using delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need download some html content (pages)  made for iphone (or mobile devices)  using delphi from a desktop application.  for example i wanna download the twitter page for iphone which look like this .

[image]

but I don't know how retrieve such pages (mobile editions), currently i using the `TIdHttp` component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need set the user agent string of your component to retrieve such pages. for the `TIdHttp` component you must set the `Request.UserAgent` property to a valid `iPhone` user agent string.

see this sample

```
 IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent:='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16';
```